# Nuxt get #hashtag part of the URL

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

`this.$route.path` gets the URL without the hashcode at the end. How do I either get the hash-part of the URL or get the full URL so I can figure out how to separate the hash part?

To be clear, for an URL like `https://example.com#test`, I'm looking the get the `test` part in a Nuxt page.

Couldn't seem to find documentation for all stuff in `$route` to see if this is something that is available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with the following

```html
<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
    console.log('mounted', this.$route.hash)
  },
}
</script>
```

In case of the following URL: `http://localhost:3000/welcome-home#hello`, it will print `#hello` to the console.
If you don't want the hash symbol, you can also do the following to only have `hello`

```js
this.$route.hash.slice(1)
```

Here is the `$route` object in that case

[image]

Here is the doc regarding the properties: https://v3.router.vuejs.org/api/#route-object-properties

Answer (score 1):

We can use string `match()` here:

```js
var url = "https://example.com#test";
var hashtag = url.match(/[^#]+$/)[0];
console.log(hashtag);
```

Comment: Thanks but how do I access the full URL from a Nuxt page to do this?

Comment: Good question, and I don't know.  My answer assumes you already have the full URL in hand.